# Google App Engine returns a 429 error when making around 100 req a minute

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am doing a perf test on a GAE server and noticed that when I make around 100 request a minute a response code 429 is return. I am not able to find any documentation that suggest this behaviour or a setting that I can increase this threshold. Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error [429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) is sent when the client has passed the limit of requests per user/ip. It is a security measure that helps against brute-forcing etc. In your case, I think you are using a package like [express rate limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) or some sort of request limiting.
If you are sure that your node application does not have such sort of feature, you need to look at app engine documentation because if you are in a free plan with no billing setup they may return this http status code(not 100% sure).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and you were right, throttling was due to rate limiting in the code. I used a Boilerplate code to get this done and it had throttling policy defined in one of the classes.